# How to get certain field from the arrayList object on spinner selection

Tags: android

I just created a spinner and make this spinner read from the database. and display them in the spinner. I already did that. But I want to right down the Id of the selected item.

for example : when I select the first raw called (1, tyat abdullah, sergurey )
I need the Id (1) only to be written down without the full record.

[image: like this]

[image: android app]

Comment: Please add your code as text, not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the Id (1) only to be written down without the full record.

Then when you are doing `labels.add`, only put the data you want to see

You can also use `doctorsList.get(position)` within the selection listener, and set the other text view accordingly.

For example, `doctorsList.get(position).getId()` seems to get the information you are asking for

Comment: yes this one of the solution but I need to put all data in the for loop because i need to display the records in the spinner like this. but I dont know how to get the id only

Comment: You already have the entire object as part of getting `doctorsList.get(position)`... How is that not enough? You said you wanted to only **show** the ID, and you therefore must modify the labels list

Comment: yes I have the entire object but if you notice that when select the first item it written down the entire object right ? but I want to be written only the Id of the object Not the entire object.

doctorsList.get(position) will start number from the 0 and up. and my id in the database is auto incremental so in the case the postion and my data will not fit

Comment: You can get the ID simply from `doctorsList.get(position).getId()`, that's my point. Whether you want to do that as part of `labels`, or in the `setText`, that's up to you

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you have things "written down" twice, and there's only two lines of code in what you've given that can change it... Currently, you're printing the entire object in both places, so one of them has to change

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you very much.
doctorsList.get(position).getId() // this is the solution that i'm looking for.

Comment: Yes Sure. Thank you again.

Comment: I could not vote up because I have less than 15 reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

simply use this to get the selected item index

```
int index = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(); //this will give you the seleected item index
```

is that what you want ?

leme Know :)

Comment: not working because getSelectedItemPosition() give the the index not my data from the database.

Comment: so write your code in such a way that your code gived you an arraylist of object which have all the required properties and then get the id from the objet


hope u r getting me :)